# If that possible to pass parameter to curl in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have a curl controller named Curl_Run_Experiment, that contained post_test function to deal with update user data. This is what the function look like:

```
function post_test(){
    $url = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$PATHNAME}/update";

    $data = array(
        'user_id'=>'',
        'fullname'=>'testing',
        'phone'=>'+6270707070707'
    );

    //init
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set opt
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    //exec
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    //close
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
}
```

My Question is can we put the parameter to the post_test function like:

```
function post_test($user_id){
    //something
}
```

so when I access the link for example (http://localhost/{$PATHNAME}/Curl_Run_Experiment/post_test/123), the curl function will recognize that the '123' is the value of $user_id.

Comment: The way you started is very convinient. Controller takes the parameter from request which you declare as `$this->uri->segment(n)` (where `n` is number of the position relative to `base_url()` [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html)). Next you would need to set correct routing if it is needed.

Comment: @Tpojka thx for your answer I'm very appreciate that. that is right I can use uri segment to the piece of the uri. Nice Logic. Would you like to submit your comment as the answer?. I'll be happy to vote up your answer as soon as I reach 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost
what is Curl in php and why it is used?

> PHP supports libcurl, a library created by Daniel Stenberg, that
>   allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of
>   servers with many different types of protocols. libcurl currently
>   supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap
>   protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP
>   PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension),
>   HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password
>   authentication.

Now if you want to hit Curl request to any URL which accepts post parameter then you can use `CURL_POST`.
and also if you want to hit Curl request to any URL which in response gives any Response then you can use `CurlGet`

E.g for Curl Get:

```
$employee_data_url = "https://urltoanyapi";
$employee_data = CurlGet($employee_data_url);
```

E.g for Curl Post:

```
$params['emailId'] = $email;
$params['password'] = $password;
$login_url ="http://url_any.com";

$response = CurlPost($login_url, $params);
```

Comment: As far as my understanding in your code is going to pass $param to $login_url but I don't have CurlPost in my lib. Can you make the flow more clear for me (more detail explaination about the CurlPost function or give me the reference for it), cuz I'm a noob for curl actually. thx I appreciate that.

Comment: Btw for the vote up I wan't to give but I can't right now. you see my reputation is below 15 so I can't vote someone but as soon as my reputation is 15 and above, I wil give vote up for your answer. once again thank you.

Comment: thank you for your explanation about curl. I'm really appreciate that.

Comment: Happy Coding :)